# Qual o ganho de se "unificar" os recursos .css e .js de um site?

Tags: javascript, css, apache

**Cenario:** Um site **X** possui 5 arquivos .css e 5 arquivos .js todos com **5KB**, um site **Y** possui o mesmo **HTML** que o site **X** porém seus recursos .css e .js estão unidos entre si (.js com .js e .css com .css).

**Pergunta:** Qual a diferença de tempo de carregamento entre as duas páginas (pode ser em porcentagem, valor bruto, o objetivo é ver se há ganho em **unificar** todos os recursos e quando o ganho começa)? existe/qual o overhead de multiplas conexões para download de .css e .js?

> **OBS:** Levo em consideração CSS de reset, CSS de bibliotecas externas,
> CSS geral e CSS especifico da página, JS de libs externas, geral e
> específicos da página.
>
> **OBS2:** Tendo como base o Apache 2.4 mas exemplos em outros servidores são bem vindos

Comment: A diferença de tempo é relativa, de qualquer forma, quanto menor o tamanho mais rápido vai carregar. Nas opções de desenvolvedor do Chrome você pode ver o tempo que cada arquivo leva para carregar na pagina.

Comment: Sim, existe overhead, você parece já saber disso. Agora, não dá pra mensurar isso de maneira geral, são muitas variáveis envolvidas. Você precisa medir a performance no seu próprio site. Mas eu diria que costuma ser vantajoso unir os arquivos sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso em que os arquivos estão juntos apenas um único request ao servidor é necessário para obter o conteúdo. Além disso compactação do arquivo tende a funcionar melhor que nos arquivos separadamente. Por este motivo geradores de Build como Grunt ou Gulp possuem opções para juntar os arquivos, "mitifica-los", e compacto-los para melhor performance geral do site.

Por outro lado isso deve ser verificado medindo para cada site específico pois arquivos JavaScript, por exemplo, podem ser carregados on-demand a medida que a página vai precisando de recursos. Por exemplo, **Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD)** permite carregar apenas o necessário para o funcionamento inicial da página. A medida que o usuário interage com a página outros recursos podem estar sendo carregados em background dando a sensação de fluidez na Interface Visual.

Em resumo, não existe uma resposta simples. A resposta dependerá do problema que esteja sendo resolvido. Se a performance é critica se faz necessário testes de Benchmark.